# How can I get programatically a cvs revision number of a file in Java?

Tags: java

I want to get a cvs revision number from a file in java. I've read that there is some libraries to do that, but I can't find them.

Maybe there is another way to do it, and I want to know.

Comment: CVS? In 2015? Really?

Comment: Yes, today, 2015. I need to do a report of updated files from a system that stills uses cvs.